# Media queries or conditional css for targeting safari on ipad/iphone?

Tags: iphone, ipad, safari, media

I've been using media queries to alter an email for iphone and ipad users. 
Basically, I've had success when emails are accessed using 'Mail' for both those devices however when accessed using Safari to log into any email client the email responds as the desktop version.

Here's what I'm using:

```
 @media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) { 
/// REST OF MY CODE HERE  /// 
}

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
/// REST OF MY CODE HERE  /// 
}
```

After a bit of research I also tried

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) and(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {  
/* CSS Statements that only apply on webkit-based browsers (Chrome, Safari, etc.) */  
/// REST OF MY CODE HERE  /// 
}
```

A few Similar questions have pointed to this page:
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/OptimizingforSafarioniPhone/OptimizingforSafarioniPhone.html

but I'm not quite sure what solution to glean from it.

Most email clients strip out javascript so I guess object detection isn't appropriate here. The User Agent String option seems more about targeting specific browser editions.

Is there a simple solution I've missed or could someone point me to an article that perhaps addresses this specific issue.

Answer (score 0):

Some (most) email provider rewrite the html/css on the webmail side. That means, it is likely that the css with the media query is parsed out. You can easily verify that, by using your regular desktop browser and inspect the code of the mail, or set some fancy colors and check out if it gets displayed.

However, I don't think that it's such a big use case that users view/access on a iphone their webmail. Is it?

Comment: Thanks for the tip biophonc. In terms of use case - you may well be right for iphone. Though stats suggest the subscriber base for this email are high means, over 40s and not necessarily tech savvy - so a lot of ipad & iphone users but I wouldn't necessarily be trusting them to use their devices in the optimum way! At least on ipad we know quite a few users access webmail.

Comment: I don't know the width of your mail template, ... but it should be not wider than 600px - that should work for the ipad as well as for regular desktop user. That leaves you alone with iphone user that view their mails via safari. btw: IIRC gmail for example does not support media queries.